# What does "check out" and "check in" actually do in Enterprise Architect version control?

Tags: svn, version-control, enterprise-architect

Lately, I started to use SVN branches to manage different versions of my model. Before I started I read official guides on version control and tried it on toy models to get the gist of it.

Now, to make things easier I'd like to write some scripts to help me manage different branches of a model. To do this efficiently and in a controlled manner I'd like to learn what does EA "check out" and "check in" commands actually do. I didn't find any documentation on this topic.

From observation and deduction I assume that "check out":

1. does `svn checkout` on a file
2. does `svn lock` on a file
3. deletes all elements from a package (without showing it)
4. imports a checked out XMI file (like 'import package from XMI file')
5. marks some flags in EA db

For "check in" I assume it:

1. exports a package to temporary XMI file (like 'export package to XMI file')
2. prompts for commit message (using "check in branch" the order of 1. and 2. is reversed)
3. if the commit message is confirmed - replaces a file in a configured directory, does `svn commit` with message (one after another, if "check in branch" is used) and `svn unlock` on every single file
4. marks some flags in EA db (like package VC status)

   I'm not sure how does EA know about missing cross-references, but it must check this after exporting a XMI file.

Can you help me finding out what is the actual process of "check out" and "check in"? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have it all figured out.

Comment: As Geert says. In any case I do not recommend using SVN (or any VC at all) since you will run into several issues.

Comment: My experience confirms your discoveries. The "some flags" in EA include date/time of the package in your VC, which is used later on by EA to determine if the package in the model is newer than in the VC.

Comment: Missing cross-references: if you exported the package with reference placeholders, then EA keeps the missing references until you import the referenced stuff (t_xref table). If not, references are lost.